# Why does Process Explorer require debug symbols to show kernel memory limits?

Tags: windows, memory, kernel, limit, symbols

`Process Explorer` (aka `procexp`) require debug symbols to show kernel memory limits and a library that provide API for reading them. As I found, the symbols for currently running kernel (`ntoskrln*`) only are required, and the variables `MmSizeOfPagedPoolInBytes` and `MmSizeOfNonPagedPoolInBytes` are read from it.  It is possible to acquire them from the kernel directly.
So why the debug symbols are required? Do they contain some information that impossible to get from the OS itself?

[image: Kernel memory limits without symbols]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Process Explorer needs to know where in kernel memory those variables are located and it can different between each version of windows so symbols are the correct way to get this location. Microsoft publish public symbols.

not all kernel information is easily access from User space.